# What is faster for searching items in list, in operator or index()?

Tags: python, performance, list, search

From this [site](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm), it says that list.index() is a linear search through the list.

And it also seems like `in` is also linear.

Is there any advantage to using one over the other?

Comment: One difference is `list.index()` returns you the index of the element in the list.

Comment: And it seems like that link is broken. Please check it out.

Comment: `index()` returns index and `in` return `True` or `False`, otherwise binary search is good if you want optimization, `log n`.

Comment: @RohitJain: link fixed (removed slash at the end).

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I think you can make a good answer out of all your comments here.

Comment: In response to the comment by @AshwiniChaudhary, a binary search only works if your array is sorted beforehand. :)

Comment: @mgilson Ah! yes, looks like I've to read my algo books again. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to compare different python approaches, such as the `in` operator versus `.index()`, use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to test the speed differences. Python data type complexities are documented on http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Do note that there is a big difference between `in` and `.index()`; the first one returns a boolean, the latter the index of the found item (an integer) or it'll raise an exception. It thus is (slightly) slower for the average case:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'a = list(range(10000))' '5000 in a'
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'a = list(range(10000))' 'a.index(5000)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 111 usec per loop
```

If you need to optimize for membership testing, use a `set()` instead:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'a = set(range(10000))' '5000 in a'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.108 usec per loop
```